# Выполнить проще

Tags: javascript

```
'https://www.site.ru/444/421.html'.match(/(.*)\/.*$/)[1]
```

Возможно ли обойтись, чтобы на выходе не массив был? То есть без этого `[1]`

На выходе получить

```
'https://www.site.ru/444/'
```

Comment: Можно, но вот не хватает деталей для грамотного ответа. Какие части ссылки могут меняться? Вам длина заранее известна или она может меняться? Это просто строчка или вы её берёте из самой ссылки страницы? Если это ссылка, то вам может помочь встроенные ф-ии JS, например https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location. Если это просто строка, то можете воспользоваться методами https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.

Comment: `match` всегда возвращает массив, если что-то нашел

Comment: `'https://www.site.ru/444/421.html'.replace(/\w*\.html$/, '')` - можно использовать [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) Если вам изсвестно что именно вы хотите отбросить с конца

Comment: результат выполнения первого блока кода не соответствует ожидаемому результату во втором блоке кода.